# Billing and Shipping details saving automatic unother details in magento 1.8.1?

Tags: mysql, magento-1.8

Billing and Shipping detail[image]s saving automatic unother details in magento 1.8.1? see below image

Comment: Insert into x select A, B, 'other stuff' from y

Comment: Mean how to and which table?